# Do the "temp files" of resumable uploads count in the monthly storage fee? (Google Cloud Storage)

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, file-transfer, gsutil

I have made several transfers via gsutil to my google cloud storage. Each transfer sent to the cloud many heavy files. I always used the multi-threaded transfer.
Some of my transfer go interrupted. For some files the transfer resume were it stopped (as we should expect with the resumable transfer) but for other, I had to give up the transfer, modify the file and restart the transfer from the beginning.

Because many of my transfers failed, and because I haven't resume them, I have a lot of temporary files* waiting for their transfer to resume. They should weight in the dozens of GB. So I wonder if they will count in my monthly storage fee and if there is a way to access these temporary files via gsutil to erase them.

*I am not sure what word I should used when I talk about the bytes of a file already transfered that enable the resumable transfer but I will use the word temporary file : the half transfered file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of November 23rd, 2015), you are not charged for the temporary storage of resumable uploads. Also, keep in mind that (from the [Resumable Uploads Recommended Practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques?hl=en#practices) page) the resumable uploads expire after one week.